# Autohotkey script to perform action when Microsoft Edge is active

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to write an script in order to perform actions when Microsoft Edge windows being active. I tried these scripts:

```
#IfWinActive Microsoft edge
~$l::
KeyWait,l,T0.25
if (ErrorLevel)
{
 send,^l
 sleep,100
 send,{Delete}
}
return
```

But it doesn't recognize the windows. I tried different names such `#IfWinActive, ahk_class Microsoft Edge` and `#IfWinActive Microsoft Edge.exe` too. but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Window Spy on a new Edge tab shows me this:

[image]

Of the three main options that you would use for an #IfWinActive statement (`WinTitle`, `ahk_class`, or `ahk_exe`), the `ahk_exe` would likely be the best option for creating a script that will always work in MS Edge, and only in MS Edge based on what the Windows Spy displays.

Based on this, I created this generic script to check if a hotkey was triggered in Edge

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe msedge.exe
^q::MsgBox Hotkey Triggered in Edge (msedge.exe)
#If

^q::MsgBox Hotkey Triggered in a different program
```

Incorporating your original script into this gives:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe msedge.exe
~$l::
KeyWait,l,T0.25
if (ErrorLevel)
{
 send,^l
 sleep,100
 send,{Delete}
}
return
```

For more info about #IfWinActive, see [the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Also relevant: [Post on AHK forums on how to use the #IfWinActive with program names, ahk_exe, and ahk_class](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=99286#p99286).